# jQuery - Get HTML of appended content in IE9 (options without select wrapper)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

After an AJAX request I get a string with some HTML data like this:

```
var test = '<div id="test-options"><option value="">Select</option><option value="true@153237119">XS</option><option value="true@153237120">S</option><option value="true@153237121">M</option><option value="true@153237122">L</option><option value="true@153237123">XL</option><option value="true@153237124">XXL</option></div><div class="athoerstuff">Ather stuff here</div>';
```

I want to append this and after it's appended get only the content of div without the wrapper:

```
var li = $(test).appendTo('form');


$("body").find('#test-options').html();
```

### -------------------------------

The **problem** was coming only on IE9 because the options without having the  wrapper.
IE9 was looking at the options inside the div and realized that this is invalid. That is why, IE9 was not getting me the options.

I added a select wrapper in the server side script where I was making the request (option values) and, instead of:

```
$('#test-options').html();
```

I added:

```
$('#test-options select').html();
```

The result result was same as previous code, but now working on IE9 as well.

Thank you all for your help.

**Maybe somebody can tell me why IE9 is not getting the options without the select wrapper and other browsers do?**

Comment: Missing quotes here $('body').find('#test-options').html(); and better to use $('#test-options').html();

Comment: Why not use `$('#test-options')` in the first place? IDs have to be unique anyway and this is probably faster than using `find`. Edit: Sorry, didn't see your edit in time.

Comment: Problem is in IE9. Trims out the options tags leaving only the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to get the `option`s html then you can simply do like below,

```
$(test).unwrap().html();
```

instead of appending to body and retrieving the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/XYhbg/

The above is under the assumption with the data that you had in the test variable. Let me know if it is any different.

Comment: It is a bit. I made a few edits. Basically my data contains multiple divs. I want to get all data, append the data, search in the data appended for the select options and append the options to a select. The problem is with IE9 that is appending to the select only the text, without any options tag, therefore no select options in the select.